# is + past perticiple? and was + past participle?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, interrogatives

- > When is the last time you danced?
- > When was the last time you danced?

Yesterday I saw the first sentence written and I don't know if it's correct.

Are both of these options correct? If so what's the difference?

Comment: Both are "correct" (syntactically valid), but *idiomatically*, native speakers would nearly always "backshift" (copula?) ***to be*** from ***is*** to ***was*** to match past tense ***danced***.